# Render 3D probability volume (3D texture) cycles / eevee

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I'm looking to render photorealistic volumes from 3D textures (think MRI scans) together with geometry.

So far, everything I've seen to do this is specific for BI, not for cycles or eevee. 
However, I don't see why it should be difficult to add a material node that takes a 3D texture (could be from a volumetric file, not necessarily a list of images) and outputs to the volume input of the output node.

I don't know enough about the internals to do it myself, though if it can be done in python it shouldn't be too difficult.

Is there any way to do this right now or should I look into creating the material node?